# Latest reputation summary is showing the +15 for an accepted answer, despite the answer being accepted months ago

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page

The reputation summary on my [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1317805/james-donnelly?tab=summary) shows this:

[image: Summary reputation display]

The +35 reputation at the top is incorrect, this should only be +10 (and shouldn't have the accepted background). This was an upvote on an answer which had been accepted months beforehand. Here is what my [reputation tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1317805/james-donnelly?tab=reputation) displays:

[image: Reputation tab display]

The answer was actually accepted on February 13th:

[image: February 13th reputation]

Comment: Maybe it got unaccepted and accepted again quickly today; causing a mini breaking of things?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: Image of an earlier date]

The author of that question unaccepted your answer and then reaccepted it on May 2nd. Since there hasn't been *that* much activity on your reputation since then, it's recent enough that the rep from that post is still visible on your recent reputation report.

Since the unaccept and the accept are separate events, the accept is rolled into the positive reputation gain, while the unaccept is a separate event. It is too old for your recent reputation report to indicate, however. That's why you see a +35 for that post (including today's upvote) but don't see anything indicating the -15.

Comment: Ah that's interesting! Would it be a bug that the previous accept vote hasn't been removed from my reputation for February 13th?

Comment: @James If we removed the accept vote from February 13th, then where would we have 15 reputation to give you -15 from? The new system basically works so that, instead of your reputation silently just... vanishing and returning at a later date, you get a traceable history.

Comment: Ah I see. I guess this isn't really an issue then!

Answer (score 2):

The thing is this question probably got unaccepted and then got accepted a few days ago.

8 Days ago to be specific.

[image]

Since you haven't had much activity in your reputation feed since May 2nd, it's still showing up on top.

Comment: Check the post's timeline for more information about its history. This page can be accessed by editing the URL: `/questions/{id}/...` -> `/posts/{id}/timeline`, http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14859934/timeline

Comment: wow totally didnt realize you could see the time an answer was accepted at. lol.